# find heading angle based on two coordinates with R programming

Tags: r, gis, trigonometry

I am trying to use the formula mentioned in this blog [HeadingAngle](https://www.igismap.com/formula-to-find-bearing-or-heading-angle-between-two-points-latitude-longitude/) and get the heading / bearing angle with the help of R Programming. Formula seems to be working correctly , **only issue** is that heading angle is coming positive for the example which I am sharing below but as per the bearing angle GIS Tool *it should be negative* -
[BearingAngleGISTool](https://www.igismap.com/map-tool/bearing-angle)

Any guide here will be really helpful what I am missing here

```
library(pracma)

longitudeA <- as.numeric(deg2rad(-0.772383960000))
latitudeA <- as.numeric(deg2rad(53.507616240000))
longitudeB <- as.numeric(deg2rad(-0.772915460000))
latitudeB <- as.numeric(deg2rad(53.506769480000))

X = cos(latitudeB)*sin(abs(longitudeB-longitudeA))

Y = (cos(latitudeA)*sin(latitudeB))- (sin(latitudeA)*cos(latitudeB)*cos(abs(longitudeB-longitudeA)))

bearingAngle <- atan2(X,Y)
bearingAngle <- rad2deg(bearingAngle)
print(bearingAngle) # 159 is not coming negative
```

If you end up with a negative answer, add 360°, and
if your answer is greater than 360°, subtract 360° from it.

Bearing would be measured from North direction i.e 0° bearing means North, 90° bearing is East,
180° bearing is measured to be South, and 270° to be West.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the worked example on the "HeadingAngle" blog?  i.e. it has "X = cos(38.627089) * sin(4.38101)" --> X =  0.05967668696, but I get "-0.5668408".

Comment: Yes , its working for me X and Y values are matching as well as per the blog - library(pracma)

longitudeA <- as.numeric(deg2rad(-94.581213))
latitudeA <- as.numeric(deg2rad(39.099912))
longitudeB <- as.numeric(deg2rad(-90.200203))
latitudeB <- as.numeric(deg2rad(38.627089))

X = cos(latitudeB)*sin(abs(longitudeB-longitudeA))

Y = (cos(latitudeA)*sin(latitudeB))- (sin(latitudeA)*cos(latitudeB)*cos(abs(longitudeB-longitudeA)))

bearingAngle <- atan2(X,Y)
bearingAngle <- rad2deg(bearingAngle)
print(bearingAngle)